# Websocket is not sending data

Tags: ios, swift, websocket

I have simple websocket server running with `npm` in the background and I am hosting the server on port `8080`.

```
import { WebSocketServer } from "ws";
import npmlog from "npmlog";

const wss = new WebSocketServer({port: "8080"})
var log = npmlog

log.info("Opening new connection in port: 8080")

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    log.info("Established new connection")
    ws.on('message', (data) => {
        log.info("Received message: " + data)

        log.info("Sending data back to connected client.")
        // ws.send('acknowledged!')
    })
})
```

And now, I have a `connectToServer(_:)` function and a `sendMessage(_:)` function in my Swift class.

```
class NetworkKit: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    private var socket: URLSessionWebSocketTask? = nil
    private var socketHasBeenEstablished = false
    
    private let logger = Logger(label: "websocket")
    
    private let operationQueue = OperationQueue()

    func connectToServer(_ address: String) throws {
        logger.info("Connecting to \(address)")
        if let url = URL(string: address) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
                let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: self.operationQueue)
                self.socket = urlSession.webSocketTask(with: urlRequest)
                self.socket?.maximumMessageSize = 10_000_0000
                self.socket?.resume()
                self.socketHasBeenEstablished = true
                self.logger.info("Connection succeeded: \(self.socketHasBeenEstablished)")
                self.socket?.send(URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message.string("sup world!"), completionHandler: { error in
                    
                })
            }
        } else {
            throw ConnectionEstablishmentFailedError.InvalidAddress
        }
    }

    func sendMessage(_ data: String) throws {
        socket?.resume()
        logger.info("Sending data: \(data) to websocket server.")
        let message = URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message.string(data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.socket?.send(message, completionHandler: { error in
                guard let error = error else {
                    self.logger.error("Unknown error")
                    return
                }
                
                self.logger.error(Logger.Message(stringLiteral: error.localizedDescription))
            })
        }
    }
```

When calling `connectToBoard(_:)` inside a button action, the device sends data to the server and the server receives it. But when calling `sendMessage(_:)` function, the server does not receive any message. But also, I don't get any error logs either.